# How do I take a Row from a DataTable and turn it into a custom Object and populate a DataGridView with it?

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

So I have a class that stores timed tasks inside of it:

```
class Task
{
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan Duration
    {
        get
        {
            if (BeginDate == DateTime.MinValue)
                return new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);
            else if (EndDate == DateTime.MinValue)
                return DateTime.Now.Subtract(this.BeginDate);
            else
                return this.EndDate.Subtract(this.BeginDate);
        }
    }

    public DateTime BeginDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public TaskStatus Status { get; set; }

    public Task()
    {
        this.Description = string.Empty;
        this.BeginDate = new DateTime();
        this.EndDate = new DateTime();
    }
}

public enum TaskStatus
{
    UNINVOICED,
    INVOICED,
    PAID
}
```

I am using DataBinding between a DataTable and a DataGridView using these columns:

```
private void AddDataGridViewColumns()
{
    dgvTimesheet.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    {
        Name = "id",
        Visible = false,
        DataPropertyName = "id"
    });

    dgvTimesheet.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    {
        Name = "description",
        HeaderText = "Description",
        Visible = true,
        DataPropertyName = "description"
    });

    dgvTimesheet.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    {
        Name = "duration",
        HeaderText = "Duration",
        Visible = true,

    });

    dgvTimesheet.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    {
        Name = "begindate",
        HeaderText = "Date Started",
        Visible = false,
        DataPropertyName = "begindate"
    });

    dgvTimesheet.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    {
        Name = "enddate",
        HeaderText = "Date Completed",
        Visible = true,
        DataPropertyName = "enddate"
    });

    dgvTimesheet.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    {
        Name = "status",
        Visible = false,
        DataPropertyName = "status"
    });
}
```

Anytime the user needs to add a new task I manually add one to the DataTable:

```
DataRow row = timesheet.Tasks().NewRow(); 
row["description"] = ActiveTask.Description; // String
row["begindate"] = ActiveTask.BeginDate; // DateTime object
row["enddate"] = ActiveTask.EndDate; // DateTime object
row["status"] = ActiveTask.Status; // Enum
```

Then I do the typical:

```
DataTable.Rows.Add(DataRow)
DataAdapter.Update(DataTable),
DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable)
```

Instead of creating a DataRow that has the same data as a Task object, is there a way to use the Task object as the object that holds data between the DataGridView and DataTable?

Every time I need to get information from the DataGridView I need to convert the value .ToString() and then parse it to the value I wanted.

So I have a DateTime object inside the datagridview ["begindate"] column but to get it back out I need to convert it to a string and parse it as a DateTime object again. It would be better if I could simply access DataGridView.Row[index].BeginDate. Is this possible?

TL;DR How do I take a Row from a DataTable and turn it into a custom Object and populate a DataGridView with it?

If you want to play around the entire project is open-source at https://github.com/codeliger/timelord

Comment: I'd copy the field values out of DataTable rows into `ObservableCollection<MyClassThatHasTheSamePropertiesAsTheTableColumns>` and use that. The "turn it into" part is a minor hassle; you could give `MyClassEtc...` a constructor that takes a `DataRow` or whatever. You could look at Entity Framework as well. It's reason for existing is basically this.

Comment: It looks like you are manually creating the DataTable to store these things.  If they never get saved/read to a DB, rather than a DataTable you could use a `List<TaskButNotSystemThreadingTasksTask>`.  It would display just  well from there in a DataGridView...and obviate the question

Comment: See webpage : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9x2790s(v=vs.110).aspx.  I don't know why you can't just use dgvTimesheet.DataSource = timesheet.Tasks();

Comment: @jdweng I tried that but when I edit an existing task it doesn't automatically update the database without a bindingsource

Comment: You are correct.  A value change in the DataSource doesn't automatically refresh the DGV.  The trick is to set the the DGV to null and then back to the dataSource.   So when you update then do following : dgvTimesheet.DataSource = null; dgvTimesheet.DataSource = timesheet.Tasks();